# TypeScript: Type 'Color' is not assignable to type '"default" | "primary" | "secondary"'

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am using MUI with typescript and facing the following error. I suspect, I am missing a very basic type of thing here but unable to catch it.

```
Error: Type 'Color' is not assignable to type '"default" | "primary" | "secondary"'.
```

I am using Chip in loop. https://material-ui.com/components/chips/

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7g6cl?file=/demo.tsx

Code is working but there is error under Color.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your badgeType has a type `PropTypes.Color` which contains `inherit` keyword that doesn't exist on the chip color prop type.
to make types compatible, you can remove it from the type

```
badgeType: Exclude<PropTypes.Color, 'inherit'>
```